# Service worker activated and is stopped, how do I instruct it to continue operating?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

[image]

When performing the following processes, the service worker will be in the `activated and is stopped` state:

1. Register the service worker
2. When visit the page, browser will have successfully installed and activated the service worker.
3. I remove the service worker file from my server
4. Close any browser tabs that are associated with the website.
5. When I return to the website and view the Application tab in the developer tool, I can see that my service worker is in the `activated and is stopped` state.
6. Put back my service worker file to my server
7. Close any browser tabs that are related to the website.
8. Return to the website; it is still in the `activated and is stopped` state.

How can the `activated and is stopped` service worker be instructed to continue?

Comment: Please see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750936/385997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have not toggled "bypass for network" in Chrome dev tools, as this will effectively cause the SW to stop.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on various circumstances, it may be reactivated.

Comment: This is much too vague to be an answer.