# Service worker will not intercept fetches

Tags: service-worker

I am serving my service worker from `/worker.js` and want it to intercept fetches to `/localzip/*`, but the `fetch` event is never fired.

I register it like this:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register(
    "worker.js",
    { scope: "/localzip/" }
);
```

And I claim all clients when it activates, so that I can start intercepting fetches from the current page immediately. I am sure that the service worker is activating and that `clients.claim()` is succeeding.

```js
self.addEventListener("activate", (e) => {
    // Important! Start processing fetches for all clients immediately.
    //
    // MDN: "When a service worker is initially registered, pages won't use it
    // until they next load. The claim() method causes those pages to be
    // controlled immediately."
    e.waitUntil(clients.claim());
});
```

Chrome seems happy with it and the scope appears correct:

[image: screenshot of Chrome Developer Tools showing active service worker]

My `fetch` event handler is very simple:

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", (e) => {
    console.log("Trying to make fetch happen!");
});
```

From my application, after the worker is active, I try to make a request, e.g.,

```js
const response = await fetch("/localzip/lol.jpg");
```

The fetch does not appear to trigger the above event handler, and the browser instead tries to make a request directly to the server and logs `GET http://localhost:3000/localzip/lol.jpg 404 (Not Found)`.

I have tried:

- Making sure the latest version of my worker code is running.
- Disabling / clearing caches to make sure the fetch isn't being handled by the browser's cache.
- Hosting from an HTTPS server. (Chrome is supposed to support service workers on plaintext `localhost` for development.)

What more does it want from me?

Live demo: https://rgov.github.io/service-worker-zip-experiment/
Note that the scope is slightly different, and the fetch is performed by creating an `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jake Archibald pointed out that I was confused about the meaning of the service worker's scope, [explained here](https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/#scope-and-control):

> We call pages, workers, and shared workers `clients`. Your service worker can only control clients that are in-scope. Once a client is "controlled", its fetches go through the in-scope service worker.

In other words:

The scope affects *which pages (clients) get placed under the service worker's control* and **not** which fetched URLs get intercepted.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's confirm you are not using hard-reload while testing your code. If you use hard-reload, all requests will not go through the service worker.
See https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/#shift-reload

I also checked `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` in Chrome, and your service worker has `fetch` handler.

[image]

Then, let's check the codes in detail.

After trying your demo page, I found a network request is handled by the service worker after clicking "Display image from zip archive" button since I can see this log:

```
Service Worker: Serving archive/maeby.jpg from zip archive
```

Then, the error is thrown:

```
Failed to load ‘https://rgov.github.io/localzip/maeby.jpg’. A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that rejected with ‘TypeError: db is undefined’.
```

This is caused by `db` object is not initialized properly. It would be worth confirming whether you see the DB related issue as I see in your demo. If not, my following statement might be incorrect.

I try to explain some service worker mechanism alongside my understanding of your code:

#### Timing of install handler

Your DB open code happens in the `install` handler only. This means DB object will be assigned only when the `install` handler is executed.
Please notice the install handler will be executed only when it's necessary. If a service worker exists already and does not need to update, the install handler won't be called. Hence, the `db` object in your code might not be always available.

#### Stop/Start Status

When the service worker does not handle events for a while (how long it would be is by browser's design), the service worker will go to stop/idle state.
When the service worker is stopped/idle (you can check the state in the devtools) and started again, the global `db` object will be `undefined`.
In my understanding, this is why I see the error `TypeError: db is undefined’`.

Whenever the service worker wakes up, the whole worker script will be executed. However, the execution of event handlers will depend on whether the events are coming.

#### How to prevent stop/idle for debugging?

Open your devtools for the page then the browser will keep it being alive.
Once you close the devtool, the service worker might go to "stop" soon.

#### Why does the service worker stops?

The service worker is designed for handling requests. If no request/event should be handled by a service worker, the service worker thread is not necessary to run for saving resources.

Please notice both `fetch` and `message` events (but not limited to) will awake the service worker.

See [Prevent Service Worker from automatically stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741922/prevent-service-worker-from-automatically-stopping)

#### Solution for the demo page

If the error is from the DB, this means the `getFromZip` function should open the DB when `db` is unavailable.

---

By the way, even without any change, your demo code works well in the following steps:

1. As a user, I open the demo page at ***the first time***. (This is for ensuring that the install handler is called.)
2. I open the devtools ASAP once I see the page content. (This is for preventing the service worker goes to `"stop"` state)
3. I click "Download zip archive to IndexedDB" button.
4. I click "Display image from zip archive" button.
5. Then I can see the image is shown properly.